# Difference between mongodb driver for PHP and mongodb database driver

Tags: php, mongodb

When I'm trying to install new dll for PHP 7 version, i am confused with the two links,

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo

Please can anyone explain the difference between these two links?

Comment: http://derickrethans.nl/mongoclient.html

Answer (score 1):

Mongo (whithoud the 'db') is the old driver. MongoDB is the new driver. You can read about the new driver at https://derickrethans.nl/new-drivers.html

The new driver is to be used with the library https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library